# Get time interval in minutes after last update

Tags: php

In a validation there needs to be an interval of 180 minutes between each update, and as a callback I want to display how many minutes it's left until it's available for "updating" again.

I have this code:

```
time() - $user['last_update']
```

It gives me the unix time  difference in seconds ($user['last_update'] is in unix time)

How can I get `time() - $user['last_update']` to show that is it i.e. "120 minutes left"?

Thankful for input

Comment: `minutes = seconds/60`???

Comment: can be done right from the db: `SELECT ..., TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,NOW(),last_update) as DIFF ...`;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this!:)

```
echo ((time() - $user['last_update'])/60)." minutes left";
```

Comment: Sometimes it's that simple! Thanks, I just added 180 like `(180-(time() - $your_workouts['last_update'])/60)` so now it's like I wanted!

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DateTime`](http://php.net/datetime) class:

```
$now = new DateTime();
$time = new DateTime($user['last_update']);
$interval = $time->diff($now);
echo $interval->format("%i minutes remaining");
```

[**Demo!**](https://eval.in/50535)